# Error rJava 64bit R&Eclipse

Tags: r, rjava

I have been trying to switch to 64-bit environment but i get stuck with rJava not working.
I have followed thread where people where having the same problem and their solution (JDK, JVM.DLL, environment variables etc..) but i am still stuck

Here is the error i get:

```
Loading required package: Rbbg
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'H:/R/R-2.15.2/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.

Failed with error:  'package 'rJava' could not be loaded'
```

Here is R.version

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32           
arch           x86_64                       
os             mingw32                      
system         x86_64, mingw32              
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.2                         
year           2012                         
month          10                           
day            26                           
svn rev        61015                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem because R can't find the jvm for the 64 architecture.

Normally if you have installed it you will get something like

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server
```

Add this to your windows path and restart R.

**Edit** To ckeck if all things are right:

Type:

```
Sys.getenv()['PATH']
```

you  get the environment variables inclusing the path for jvm.dll. If youd'ont have the jvm path here you need to add it using the usual Advanced System Settings  method and restart your R console so this take effect.

```
Sys.getenv()['ProgramW6432']
```

You get C:\Program Files for the 64 archtitecture.

Comment: I have created a JVM_DLL variable already pointing at:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\jre\bin\server and added %JVM_DLL% to Path. It is correct no ?

Comment: you can check your path in R using Sys.getenv()['PATH'] and get the Program Files paths for 64 using Sys.getenv()['ProgramW6432'].

Comment: When i type Sys.getenv()['PATH'] in Rterm 64bit I get the environment variables I except including the path for jvm.dll. When i type Sys.getenv()['ProgramW6432'] i just get C:\\Program Files. Here is the error? Can you help, explain why? Thank you

Comment: I get all the variables i expect in Sys.getenv()['PATH'] including the jvm.dll path and get C:\Program Files as expected with Sys.getenv()['ProgramW6432']. So nothing here, right?